# how to print sorted permutation of a string with recursion in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, recursion

i want to print permutations of a string in a sorted way. and i am not allowed to use itertools and i must do it with recursion.

this is the code that i created for this purpose but it is very slow as for 10 characters it takes 200s to print all answers! i want to make it faster to do it in 10s . any help?

```
n = int(input()) # n is the number of characters

1 <= n <= 10

elements0 = str(input()) # it will be in this format : A B C D E F G

elements = elements0.split()

def translate(elements) :
    i = 0
    while i < n :
        elements[i] = int(i)
        i = i + 1
    return elements

elements = translate(elements)

def factor(elements,i):
    elements = elements[:]
    if i == len(elements) - 1:
        list.append(elements)
        return elements
    else:
        for j in range(i,len(elements)):
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]
            factor(elements, i + 1)
            elements[i], elements[j] = elements[j], elements[i]

list = []

factor(elements,0)

list = sorted(list)

def untranslate(list,n) :
    from math import factorial
    i = 0
    while i < factorial(n) :
        k = 0
        while k < n :
            if list[i][k] == 0 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[0]
            if list[i][k] == 1 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[2]
            if list[i][k] == 2 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[4]
            if list[i][k] == 3 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[6]
            if list[i][k] == 4 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[8]
            if list[i][k] == 5 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[10]
            if list[i][k] == 6 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[12]
            if list[i][k] == 7 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[14]
            if list[i][k] == 8 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[16]
            if list[i][k] == 9 :
                list[i][k] = elements0[18]
            k = k + 1
        i = i + 1
    return list

list = untranslate(list,n)



while True :
    if list == [] : break
    else:
        i=0
        row = str()
        while i < n :
            row = row + str(list[0][i])
            i = i + 1
        list.pop(0)

        print(row) # This should be in this format : ABCDEFG
```

and another point : the way i want to sort is not A B C D ... (alphabetic) . character's values are as they appear in elements0 . for example if elements0 is B A , it must be printed BA AB .

Comment: @e-satis yes bro. how would u got it ? :D

Comment: You listen in class and read the book.

Comment: @TimTisdall i posted the code that i wrote. i think that means i know something. but the problem is that is a better code to write that i don't know how to do it.

Comment: He was honest and worked. Post is well written, no reason not to help.

Comment: sorry.  all the homework questions I've seen on here has made me jaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since this is homework, I can give you a version that varies slightly from what you're trying to achieve.

Remember in recursion, you need two things:

1. Base case
2. Faith in your function that it will solve everything other than the base case.

Here is the code

```
def getPermutations(string):
    if len(string) == 1: # Base Case
        return [string]
    else:                # Not base case
        result = []
        for i in range(len(string)):
            candidate = string[i]
            remaining = string[0:i] + string[i+1:]
            babies = getPermutations(remaining)  # Faith!
            for word in babies:
                result.append(candidate + word)
        return result
```

This definitely does not take 200s for "ABCD". The code is self documenting, so you should be able to figure out what's being done here.

Here's a sample run.

```
>>> myPerms = sorted( getPermutations("ABC") )
>>> for p in myPerms: print p
... 
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CAB
CBA
```

Note that this won't work if the string has duplicate entries (e.g. "AABC"). Good luck with your homework!

Comment: +1 for "1. Base case 2. Faith in your function that it will solve"

Comment: @e-satis What? Did I do the whole thing? Should I not have?

Comment: For a homework question, it's better to give pointers than to give the whole answer at the begining. Once the OP has figure it out, you update your with the clean version, so it helps others. It's not a big deal, but you'll know for next time.

Comment: @e-satis Well, I must admit my greed for rep affected my judgment here. I will keep what you said in mind from now on. Sorry.

Comment: @slider thank you much! i was typed this code but my problem was that i didn't know how to get result in list in 2 cases. and this section "for p in myPerms: print p" . and another point: i said i want to sort by appearance in elements0 . "sorted()" didn't work . so i cleared "sorted()" and it was sorted itself the way i wanted !

Comment: @user3015255 Glad to hear things are working out for you. `for p in myPerms: print p` was just to show you what was in the list. You can have your own different for loop if you want the words printed in a different manner. Play with the code and see what works best.